# How do I program my WCF service in the given scenario?

Tags: wcf

I am currently developing a C# Windows Form Application that I intend to let it interact with a server. The server will receive posting from a mobile application that I have developed and whenever a posting is received, my Windows Form Application should be notified and give me a notification.

E.g. My mobile application sends an message over to my server. Once my server receives the message, my windows form application should display a new notification showing the content of the message received.

I am now starting to develop the WCF service and has reach the PostingService method and I am unsure of how I am able to continue to program the service to work the way I wan as stated above.

```
public class PostingService : IPostingService
{
    public void NotifyAboutPosting(Posting post)
    {
        // do something with post here
    }
}
```

and after I program the service, how do I test the service by, I dunno? uploading a fake post to see if the services works or whatsoever , meaning a dummy test. thanks !

**EDIT**

for my main method, the code are as follows ,

```
Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost/");

        ServiceHost selfHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(IPostingService), baseAddress);

        try
        {

            selfHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IPostingService),new WSHttpBinding(),     "Posting");

            ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
            smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
            selfHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

            selfHost.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("The service is ready.");
            Console.WriteLine("Press <ENTER> to terminate service.");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.ReadLine();

            selfHost.Close();
        }
        catch (CommunicationException ce)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("An exception occurred: {0}", ce.Message);
            selfHost.Abort();
        }
```

basically I just followed through the tutorial given by MSDN WCF getting started tutorial. not sure if this is really the correct way to do it for the type of implementation that I want.

Comment: I think your question might more accurately be 'how do I program my windows form application?' - the manner in which your program is structured will determine how you proceed.

Comment: currently my winform application has been almost 90% developed except for the last part which is to receive the notification. hence I am now creating the WCF service, followed by writing the service code in the winform app. however I am still stuck at the first part which is implementing the service method. thanks for reply!

Comment: sometimes it's a good idea to do the bit you don't know first ;-)

Comment: @Thomas: added another answer - hopefully that'll clear up a few things. If you send me an e-mail (mscheuner -at- gmail -dot- com), I can send you the sample. Also: in your code, you must use the **service IMPLEMENTATION class** in your `ServiceHost` constructor - **NOT** the service contract (interface)! So use `ServiceHost selfHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(PostingService), baseAddress)` (important: `typeof(PostingService)` - **NOT** `typeof(IPostingService)`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) **PostingService** assembly (class-library project)

Interface: **IPostingService.cs**

```
using System;
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace PostingService
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IPostingService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        void NotifyAboutPosting(Posting posting);
    }
}
```

---

Implementation: **PostingService.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace PostingService
{
    public class PostingService : IPostingService
    {
        public void NotifyAboutPosting(Posting posting)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(posting.Message, posting.Title, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
    }
}
```

---

DataContract: **Posting.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace PostingService
{
    [DataContract]
    public class Posting
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Message { get; set; }
    }
}
```

2) Your **Winforms app** (Winforms application project)

Must reference the service assembly (since it needs the service contract and the data contract class)

Main Form of your app: **Form1.cs**

```
using System;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using PostingService;   // your class library from above

namespace WinformsApp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private ServiceHost _host = null;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // IMPORTANT: here you need the **SERVICE IMPLEMENTATION CLASS** in the typeof() (*NOT* the interface!)
            _host = new ServiceHost(typeof(PostingService), new Uri("http://localhost:8888/PostingService"));

            ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
            smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
            _host.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

            _host.Open();

            label2.Text = "Service up and running (http://localhost:8888/PostingService)";
        }

        protected override void OnFormClosed(FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            _host.Close();

            base.OnFormClosed(e);
        }
    }
}
```

3) Run your Winforms app - now that service is up and running and ready to be notified.

4) Launch [WCF Test Client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552364.aspx) (that's what your "posting server" will be doing later on)

4a) File > Add Service - type in http://localhost:8888/PostingService - should find your service

4b) if found: enter some values into the properties for the "Posting" class (an ID, title, message)

[image]

4c) Click "Invoke" - your service should now be called, a dialog pop (message box) should pop up with the title and message you've defined

Comment: hi, thanks for this reply. it helped quite abit. for the winform part, after adding the reference PostingService by right clicking at the solution explorer and adding it in, there is still an error of the type or namespace 'PostingService' could not be found.

Comment: @Thomas: did you include `using PostingService;` in your main form's .cs file ?? Just adding the assembly reference isn't enough - you need to add the `using` clause, too

Comment: yes. i added it to my mainForm.cs. as my winform app contains several forms, which is the form the user will see after it logins through the loginForm. I have sent an email to you also. and it seems that I cant find the wcftestclient.exe as well.

Comment: edit again : managed to fix it by changing to using wcfserviceimplementation instead of using postingservice. thanks!

Comment: @Thomas: oops, sorry - my bad - I had a mixup with some namespace names there....

Comment: this does works fine, but in this way, the service is hosted at the application side. I need to convert this into 2 seperate programs as I cant ask the server to always connect to the application. It is possible to convert all this into just a service application right?

Answer (score 2):

Well, your WCF service can do anything you want - so what do you really want it to do??

Your posting server gets a new message from a mobile device, and then calls this WCF service class in your Winforms app. **What do you want to happen here and now**??

One thing to keep in mind: the WCF service class receiving the message and the Winforms app might be running on different threads; if that's the case, you cannot just update e.g. UI elements on your Winforms UI from the service code (you need to use some synchronization methods). But that depends on your exact way of creating and opening the `ServiceHost` in your Winforms app.

**Update:** if you put your code to create and initialize your `ServiceHost` into the main application form (see [Service Synchronization Context on CodeIdol](http://codeidol.com/csharp/wcf/Concurrency-Management/Service-Synchronization-Context/) for a sample on how to do this), then you could probably just do:

```
public class PostingService : IPostingService
{
    public void NotifyAboutPosting(Posting post)
    {
       MessageBox.Show(post.Title, post.Message, 
                       MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
}
```

assuming your `Posting` class has both a `.Title` and a `.Message` string property...

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your reply once again. It works like this, a help button is pressed on my mobile app, it post the alert to the server, the service reads that a new alert is posted, my winform app gives a pop up stating a new alert has been received. sort of like how MSN works when someone logs in and a notification pops up saying someone has logged in.

Comment: so sorry if you feel irritated by my question. as i'm still pretty new in this area, there is little stuff that i know about wcf :/

Comment: @Thomas: can you show us the code used to instantiate and open the `ServiceHost` ?? Where and how are you doing that?? (please update your question with this info - don't put it into a comment - really really hard to read, since you cannot format code properly in comments....)

Comment: @Thomas: thanks for the code - however, it's still not clear to me **WHERE** you run this code. Is this inside your main form?? In your `program.cs` file?? Where is this code contained in?? Check out [Service Synchronization Context](http://codeidol.com/csharp/wcf/Concurrency-Management/Service-Synchronization-Context/) - this programmer shows how to put your `ServiceHost` into your main form, so that you get the benefit of the default "synchronization context"

Comment: yes. the code is in another project apart from my winform app. in the service project there is just a file program.cs and in that file, in the main method it contains the code.

Comment: hi, for the messagebox, it seems that there is an error saying that messagebox does not exist in current context.

Comment: @Thomas: add `using System.Windows.Forms;` at the top of your file, plus possibly an assembly reference (in your Solution Explorer)

Comment: hi, so how does the service knows if a posting has been made to the server?

Comment: @Thomas: the posting server needs to call this service; so in your posting server (a .NET app, too??), you need to create a WCF client-side proxy (using "Add Service Reference" or svcutil.exe) and then you need to **call that service** and the appropriate method on that service....

Comment: so for my winform app, where do I code the service part. in program.cs? or the mainForm where its suppose to show the alert.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps WCF callbacks might meet your requirements:

[What You Need To Know About One-Way Calls, Callbacks, And Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163537.aspx)